# When pm2 forked app is running how can i reload the configuration file and restart with minimal downtime?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a node.js app that runs flawlessly and its ready for production.  My question is once its up and running (a single server.js file is running as x number of forked processes via PM2), and I need to make a change to the configuration.json file (which defines the processes/instances along with some custom environment variables), how can I use PM2 command such as PM2 reload 0 or something to have PM2 'pick up' / detect / make use of the changes to the configuration.json file (for example the environment variables or log file path).

I'm hoping to be able to make changes to ONE instance of the forked app (in the configuration.json file) and restart it, with the NEW config data, restart it alone, and have the other forked processes continue to run with no interruption.

Is this possible?  Or do I need to do

```
pm2 kill
pm2 flush
pm2 restart x // where x is the ID number for the PM2 process / instance
```

... then restart the PM2 Daemon using my startup normally?